# Reason why this background color won't override the other?

Tags: css

Although it works with !important I would rather avoid using it.. Can anyone explain to me why this won't override the other?

```
#g1 div div {
    background: #fefefe;
}

#winnar {
    background: #a2f5ff;
}
```

and the the html

```
<div>
    <div>Price</div>
    <div id="winnar">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

I thought do to specificity the one at the bottom should override the one on the top? Or is the top one too specific? If so, how can I make the bottom one override the top one? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought do to specificity the one at the bottom should override the
>   one on the top?

No, because the first one has 1 id selector and two tagname selectors. But the second one only has 1 id selector.

Then, the first one wins.

You can find the exact formula here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

In general, if you want the second rule to have more specificity, make sure that one rule is contained in the other:

```css
#g1 div div { background: #fefefe; }
#g1 div div#winnar { background: #a2f5ff; }
```

But in this specific case better use

```css
#g1 div div { background: #fefefe; }
#g1 #winnar { background: #a2f5ff; }
```

But be aware that multiple descendant selectors can be slow. Try using childhood selectors if possible:

```css
#g1 > div > div { background: #fefefe; }
#g1 #winnar { background: #a2f5ff; }
```

Comment: Ahhhhh ok! Thanks! Any way I could like.. force the #winnar div to have more specificity without changing the #g1 div div ?

Comment: Ah I never knew that descendant selectors were slower than childhood selectors. Huh. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @shanling Not at all :) . I have improved the selector for your specific case

Comment: You can also (if used sparingly) use: `#winnar { background: #a2f5ff !important; }` for certain elements of this type. More info can be found here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: @rand'Chris Yes, `!important` can do the trick, but it must be the last option.

Comment: @Oriol I didn't even notice that !important was mentioned in the original question. Oh well, sorry for the noise (twice now).